# Mixed model and missing data

Tags: missing-data, mixed-models

I have built a mixed effects linear regression model of a behavioral variable recorded on 16 individuals over the course of a year at 6 time points. The model showed a significant effect of time on the dependent variable.

Data are missing for 6 of the 16 individuals at the last time point (due to attrition). The reviewer of the paper (who is unfamiliar with mixed effects models) is suggesting that the effect of time is not real because there are missing data at the final time period. I computed an effect size for the Time effect and it was small.

**I have heard that mixed effects models are robust even with missing data, but can't seem to find references for this, nor do I understand why this would be the case.** Would anyone be able to offer a suggestion as to how I might rebut this reviewer's take on the data?

Comment: Do you have missing data only on the dependent variable, or do missing values also occur on independent variables?

Comment: Hi Simon, the subjects have the dependent variable measured at different times (time is an independent variable in this longitudinal design). Some subjects dropped out of the study before others, hence the missing values.